# How would you forget cached Eloquent models in Laravel?

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-4

Theoretical question on Laravel here.

So Example of the caching I'd do is:

```
Article::with('comments')->remember(5)->get();
```

Ideally I'd like to have an event for Article updates that when the ID of a instance of that model (that's already cached) is updated I want to forget that key (even if it's the whole result of the query that's forgotten instead of just that one model instance), it is possible to do so?

If not is there some way to implement this reasonably cleanly?

Comment: not so theoretical, btw.

Comment: Not now it's answered but at the time it was because there was no documentation on using cache keys with eloquent

Answer (score 60, accepted):

So i was looking for an answer to the same question as OP but was not really satisfied with the solutions. So i started playing around with this recently and going through the source code of the framework, I found out that the `remember()` method accepts second param called `key` and for some reason it has not been documented on their [site](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#caching-queries) (Or did i miss that?).

Now good thing about this is that, The database builder uses the same cache driver which is configured under `app/config/cache.php` Or should i say the same cache system that has been documented here - [Cache](http://laravel.com/docs/cache). So if you pass min and key to `remember()`, you can use the same key to clear the cache using `Cache::forget()` method and in fact, you can pretty much use all the `Cache` methods listed on the [official site](http://laravel.com/docs/cache), like `Cache::get()`, `Cache::add()`, `Cache::put()`, etc. But i don't recommend you to use those other methods unless you know what you're doing.

Here's an example for you and others to understand what i mean.

`Article::with('comments')->remember(5, 'article_comments')->get();`

Now the above query result will be cached and will be associated with the `article_comments` key which can then be used to clear it anytime (In my case, I do it when i update).

So now if i want to clear that cache regardless of how much time it remembers for. I can just do it by calling `Cache::forget('article_comments');` and it should work just as expected.

Hope this helps everyone :)

Comment: Good answer, thank you. For those who are unclear, the first argument to remember is the number of minutes to cache. http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Query.Builder.html#881-893

Comment: Late to the party, but this doesn't work for me. Doesn't return any data.

Comment: @Alias what version of Laravel you used? It should work fine unless they made some changes in recent versions which I'm yet to take a look.

Comment: In recent versions, the cache functions are no longer built into the model. One must cache the results from the model explicitly, not as part of the chained functions.

Answer (score 14):

I think a good way to do is like [this](http://laravel.com/docs/cache#cache-sections):

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function()
{
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```

and then use [Model Observers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers) to detect the event of updating the model

```
class UserObserver {

    public function saving($model)
    {
        //
    }

    public function saved($model)
    {
        // forget from cache
        Cache::forget('users');
    }

}

User::observe(new UserObserver);
```

Comment: When I run DB::table('users')->get(); this won't get instances of a Eloquent model will it, it'll only get the results of the query as an array of generic objects? Thought I assume I can return the result of the Eloquent model query rather than a direct DB query right?

Comment: I believe you should use `User::whereSomething('something')->get()` if you want to cache the Eloquent collection of objects and if you want to just store the properties to convert it to an array like: `User::whereSomething('something')->get()->toArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no easy way. However I found this workaround, which so far worked for me.

First you have to extend `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.

```
<?php 

class ModifiedBuilder extends Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {
    protected $forgetRequested = false;

    public function forget() 
    {
        $this->forgetRequested = true;
    }

    public function getCached($columns = array('*'))
    {
        if (is_null($this->columns)) $this->columns = $columns;

        list($key, $minutes) = $this->getCacheInfo();

        // If the query is requested ot be cached, we will cache it using a unique key
        // for this database connection and query statement, including the bindings
        // that are used on this query, providing great convenience when caching.
        $cache = $this->connection->getCacheManager();

        $callback = $this->getCacheCallback($columns);

        if($this->forgetRequested) {
            $cache->forget($key);
            $this->forgetRequested = false;
        }

        return $cache->remember($key, $minutes, $callback);
    }
}
```

Then you have to create new class which extends Eloquent Model.

```
<?php

class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    protected function newBaseQueryBuilder() {
        $conn = $this->getConnection();

        $grammar = $conn->getQueryGrammar();

        return new ModifiedBuilder($conn, $grammar, $conn->getPostProcessor());
    }
}
```

Now when creating Eloquent Models, instead of extending `Eloquent` Models extend newly created `BaseModel`.

Now you can `remember` query result as usual.

```
YourModel::remember(10)->get();
```

When you want to discard the cached result all you have to do is

```
YourModel::forget()->get();
```

If you remember the result previously, after clearing the cached result, model will continue to remember the result for that amount of time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the getCached method, where does the $key variable get initiated?

Comment: It is retrieved in `getCacheInfo()` function and the key is generated in `generateCacheKey()` function in [`Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php).

Apparently you can set your own key by using in `remember()` method according to the API. However it seems to be neglected in the `getCacheKey()` function.

Comment: The method I mentioned above works pretty well for the simple queries and most of the relationships. However when pivot table is present (in many to many relationships it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing for debug mode. So I found that if you put a test for app.debug in a constructor you are able to clear the cache associated with a key. Saves you having to duplicate the code for every function.

```
class Events {
    public function __construct() {
        if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
            Cache::forget('events');
        }
    }

    public static function all() {
        $events = \DB::table('events as e')
            ->select('e.*')
            ->where('enabled', 1)
            ->remember(30, 'events')
            ->get();

        return $events;
    }
}
```