# Cache key on eloquent model with pagination

Tags: php, caching, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to cache eloquent result on laravel 4 using,

```
Model::with('something')->remember(time, key)->pagination(total);
```

but it gives me the following error,

```
ErrorException. Trying to get property of non-object
```

When I remove the key,

```
Model::with('something')->remember(time)->pagination(total);
```

it works fine.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

```
Model::with('something')->remember(time, key)->pagination(total);
```

Caching did not work because `remember()` expecting only one parameter and parameter must be a number (time in minutes). In addition, You don't need to pass any key to cache the result.

```
Model::with('something')->remember(10)->pagination(total);
```

In this example, the results of the query will be cached for ten minutes. While the results are cached, the query will not be run against the database, and the results will be loaded from the default cache driver specified for your application.

Comment: I used it on other model without pagination and still works fine. I could use key as a second parameter like described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542890/how-would-you-forget-cached-eloquent-models-in-laravel. The problem only arises when I tried to use pagination

Comment: any idea how to delete pagination cache before the expiration time?